# Looping in PLSQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, loops, plsql

Have you ever been working on something, found an easier way to do it, completed the project, but still wanted to get the first way to work?

Thats where I'm at right now. I wanted to count the number of instances in a column where the most recent number and the preceding number are not equal. I decided to do this with a while loop.

For example,

```
4
3
2
1
1
1
0
0
0
```

would return 3, as 4 decreases to 1 in three intervals.

```
4
4
3
2
1 
0 
0
```

would return 0, as 4 does not decrease in the most recent interval.

I have written

```
declare 
   cursor curr
   is 
          select (YTDOVERDRAFTS - Previous_YTDOVERDRAFTS) colum
          from (select LAG(YTDOVERDRAFTS,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY EFFDATE asc) As Previous_YTDOVERDRAFTS,
           YTDOVERDRAFTS
               from WH_ACCTDEPOSIT
               where ACCTNBR = xxxxxxxxx
               order by effdate desc);
   Counter BINARY_INTEGER :=0;
   readcurr curr%ROWTYPE;
   status INTEGER;
begin 
  open curr; 
  fetch curr into readcurr;
  while readcurr.colum > 0
    loop       
        Counter := Counter + 1;  
        dbms_output.put_line(Counter);
        dbms_output.get_line(Counter, status);
    end loop;
    close curr;
end;
```

which runs, but does not give the output it should. What am I doing wrong with the dbms_output statements?

Comment: shouldn't you be refetching `curr` inside the loop?

Comment: Why? once the data is in the cursor why would I have to refetch it?

Comment: Doesn't your query return multiple rows?  You need to `fetch` for each row, no?

Comment: no my query will just return an integer

Comment: I'm sorry for half reading your code, but how does the loop end if the condition is `while readcurr.colum > 0`, and the value of `readcurr.column` will never change during the loop?

Comment: @joel no, that query will return one row for each row in the WH_ACCTDEPOSIT table with the given account number.  You are only fetching the first row; and I'm guessing that row returns a value of 0, because if it returned a larger value you would be hitting an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a single query can do this, I modified your query please check below:

```
select sum((case when (YTDOVERDRAFTS - Previous_YTDOVERDRAFTS) <> 0 then 1 else 0 end)) non_equal_count
      from (select LAG(YTDOVERDRAFTS,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY EFFDATE asc) As Previous_YTDOVERDRAFTS,
       YTDOVERDRAFTS
           from WH_ACCTDEPOSIT
           where ACCTNBR = xxxxxxxxx);
```

Comment: I already have the project done, I really just want to get the loop working so I can give myself a pat on the back and say "good job".